# jasmine-allure-reporter, display test cases separately based on spec files

Tags: jasmine, protractor, report, allure

I'm using Protractor and jasmine-allure-reporter
And trying to run multiple specs that are defined in the config.js file.
specs: ['spec1.js','spec2.js']

spec1.js contains 3 tests and spec2.js contains single test.But the jasmine-allure-reporter displays all the four test cases(3+1) together and there is no specification about the spec files (spec file name). How can I display the test cases separately under each spec file-name in one HTML. 
Please help me on this.

I am generating report using command "allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report || true"

allure-results >> Location where xml files are generated and 
allure-report >> where html report is generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the allure reporter repository, it doesn't look like it's supported. They set the [`outDir`](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-jasmine/blob/master/src/Jasmine2AllureReporter.js#L21) but do not expose a way to `consolidateAll` like how jasmine-reporter does. See [jasmine-reporter GitHub](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters/blob/master/src/junit_reporter.js#L177). If you decide to switch to jasmine-reporter, consolidating XML files is pretty simple. See the [Protractor cookbook for an example](https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook/blob/master/jasmine-junit-reports/conf.js#L10).

Comment: I have to go with allure. Anyway thanks for the info.

Comment: HI @user2176592 did you find any solution or workaround for this? Thanks